# How to redirect from http://www.websitename.com/index.html to http://www.websitename.com/

Tags: html, redirect

I am working on a website basically build using html css.
I am stuck on the redirection state. 
When someone open

```
www.websitename.com
```

its open fine as well as the website open in this url also

```
www.websitename.com/index.html
```

How to stop opening or redirect website to the root when someone open

```
www.websitename.com/index.html
```

Comment: Well @Paulie_D I did and try by myself,  When not found something useful then I ask

Comment: You have to DEMONSTRATE what you tried so we don't repeat code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create .htaccess file in root folder and add the below code.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^index\.html$ / [R=301,L]
```